# UICollectionView founds nil when trigger again reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift

When I what to remove all the actuall data from the collection view and add new data, pass the error **Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** when trigger again **reloadData()**. Here's the code where pops up.

```
func getAllProducts(){
    print("All products before getting again from the func: \(productsAll.count)")

    productsAll.removeAll()

    refProducts.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let productsDic = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else {return}

        for(_, productSelected) in productsDic{
            guard let name = productSelected["name"] as? String else {return}
            guard let imageURLString = productSelected["image"] as? String else {return}
            guard let price = productSelected["price"] as? String else {return}
            guard let description = productSelected["description"] as? String else {return}

            guard let imgURL = URL(string: imageURLString) else {return}
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imgURL) else {return}
            guard let img = UIImage(data: data) else {return}

            let productData = Product(productImage: img, productName: name, productPrice: price, productDescription: description, productRecommended: false)

            self.productsAll.append(productData)
            print("We have \(self.productsAll.count) products in All products")



        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How  do you trigger the second `reloadData()`  ? by calling this method also ?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? Is it the line calling `reloadData` or is it some other code triggered by the reload? How is `self.collectionView` declared and initialized? What is `self` here? Is it a `UIViewController` or a `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: `productsAll.removeAll()` at the starting for what reason?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, in other function trigger the first reloadData() when loads the view, then when the switch changes value, trigger the function of my question

Comment: @rmaddy It's a UICollectionViewController. And the reloadData() cause the crash.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia When the switch changes value, to have empty the array of productsAll, and not have olders elements loaded.